# Using MSGPACK_DEFINE without changing class declarations

Tags: c++, msgpack, messagepack

Is there a way in MsgPack C++ to use MSGPACK_DEFINE without altering the class members? We'd like to keep message pack stuff out of the headers, and only use it internally in a library.

It seems like just wrapping each class would work, but am hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

**UPD**. Alternatively you can use `MSGPACK_DEFINE_EXTERNAL` macro I wrote.

The `.hpp.erb` source is available [here](https://gist.github.com/xyzz/2181e5f03a420bd7451f/raw/83f9ca06adb14d8255ceb476f914efec58b7f8b5/gistfile1.txt), and generated `.hpp` is [here](https://gist.github.com/xyzz/3e1ee4b47fff1b48b916/raw/e9a7e9522cf69419b73acc1cae3752c04f473b4f/gistfile1.cpp).

Just `#include "define_external.hpp"`, and then call `MSGPACK_DEFINE_EXTERNAL` passing in the class and its members you want to be serialized/deserialized.

For example:

```
MSGPACK_DEFINE_EXTERNAL(v3f, X, Y, Z);
```

I've tested this header file to work with gcc 4.8.2, clang 3.3 and MSVC 2010.

---

To achieve this in my project I just defined `operator>>` and `operator<<`. This is not as straightforward as just using `MSGPACK_DEFINE`, but it works.

```
namespace msgpack {

inline v3f& operator>> (object o, v3f& v)
{
    if(o.type != type::ARRAY) { throw type_error(); }
    if(o.via.array.size != 3) { throw type_error(); }
    o.via.array.ptr[0].convert(&v.X);
    o.via.array.ptr[1].convert(&v.Y);
    o.via.array.ptr[2].convert(&v.Z);
    return v;
}

template <typename Stream>
inline packer<Stream>& operator<< (packer<Stream>& o, const v3f& v)
{
    o.pack_array(3);
    o.pack(v.X);
    o.pack(v.Y);
    o.pack(v.Z);
    return o;
}

}
```

You can find more examples in `src/msgpack/type/`.